# file with path > MAX_PATH and inserting binary into DB

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I pulled a `SafeFileHandle` via some P/Invoke.  Here's a snippet:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string lpFileName,
        EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
        EFileShare dwShareMode,
        IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
        ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
        EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

Then I can grab the handle pretty easily:

```
SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile(path, EFileAccess.GenericRead, EFileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero,ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I have to do this because `System.IO.File` only takes a string path and I need to support fully qualified paths greater than the 260 character `MAX_PATH`.

Anyways, I have a command procedure on sql server to perform an insert.  I am currently adding the byte array of the stream to a `varbinary(max)` column (most of my files are less than 2MB so `filestream` didn't seem worth going to).

I'm currently populating the command parameter like so:

```
using (FileStream s = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[s.Length];
    s.Read(buf, 0, Convert.ToInt32(s.Length));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", buf);
}
```

It just seems really slow compared to the usual `File.ReadAllBytes` that I could use with a file path less than `MAX_PATH`.  Is there a more optimal way to put this binary into the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag in dwFlagsAndAttributes. Since you are reading the entire file in one go, the buffering that is built into native Windows IO is unnecessary and adds a little bit of overhead. Not sure how much it'll save you, but sometimes every little bit helps.